# svn load issue while loading a dump to a existing repository

Tags: svn

I am trying to load dump say "load.dump" to a particular directory of a repository path say `projects/branches/A` in the svn server

```
svnadmin load --parent-dir branches/A path/to/projectrepository < load.dump
------- Committed new rev xxxx (loaded from original rev xx) >>>

<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision xxx

------- Committed new rev xxxx (loaded from original rev xxx) >>>

<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision xxx

------- Committed new rev xxxxx (loaded from original rev xxx)
```

After executing above command i see the only the revision numbers updated but no files/data from source dump gets updated in the destination directory(project/branches/A).

I am newbie to svn world, still learning the things... Please let me know if I am missing something here.

Comment: just found out that when i try loading the complete dump say completerepo.dump with the below command it works fine..files/folders gets into the new repos                                                 svnadmin load --parent-dir branches/A path/to/projectrepository <load.dump  so the problem is with                                                       svndumpfilter include branches < completerepo.dump > load.dump            svndumpfilter include seems to be not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

`svnadmin load` successfully loaded revisions from this "load.dump" according to the command output you've specified. You have to check revision history to see where the loaded data resides. For example, run [`svn log -v`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html) against the repository and see paths affected by loaded revisions.

Comment: just found out that when i try loading the complete dump say completerepo.dump with the below command it works fine..files/folders gets into the new repos                                                 svnadmin load --parent-dir branches/A path/to/projectrepository <load.dump  so the problem is with                                                       svndumpfilter include branches < completerepo.dump > load.dump            svndumpfilter include seems to be not working as expected

Comment: @user3467431 you should update your question with this info. You didn't specify that you've filtered the dump using `svndumpfilter` tool. Most likely, values of include / exclude arguments were invalid, so the dump lacks data you want to load.